# Can you view your total armor rating?

Tags: xbox-one, the-elder-scrolls-online

Is there a way to see your character's total equipped armor rating?

For example, if I'm wearing 5 pieces of gear, each having 10 Armor, is there somewhere in the character/inventory to see that added up to 50?

I'm on console, Xbox One, but I'd hope this isn't a console specific question.

Comment: On the PC, it's listed in the character screen ("C" by default). The same screen is found on the console, though slightly modified. It appears that Armor Rating is missing on the console, which does make this a console-only question, unfortunately.

Comment: very annoying! thanks for the info though, wonder why there's  a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reposting an answer from a comment:

No, it is not a visible stat in the console version of ESO. It looks like launch version of ESO has omitted the total armor rating for some reason, on console only.